# Eslint destructuring props - allow single props without destructing

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-props

> Reason for this question is easier working in bigger component, you
>   always need to scroll at various lines,
>   **I think that single-props is
>   enough intuitive for "safe" usage.**

In many cases, there are methods that call reducer i.e.

and I think it can be used without destructing props and **still keep code readability at high level**

```
      /**
       * Example with destructed props
       */
      removeItem(item) {
        const { remove } = this.props;

        remove(item);
      }
```

At the example below, we can save many lines of code in component.

```
      /**
       * Example without destructed props
       */
      removeItem(item) {
        this.props.remove(item);
      }
```

How to set up eslint to allow single-props without destructing and to be mandatory if more than one?

I would like to avoid the eslintuse of **`eslint disable line`** comment

I was unable to figure form documentation how to do that
[eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring)

Does anybody have an idea how to walkaround this?

Comment: AFAIK right now you can't alter this behavior, which also annoys me on occasion--but it's also not a big deal.